# Evaluate Geometric Sums

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do I evaluate the following??
I keep using a= 1/5 and r=1/4 for

```
         $a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$
```

but I obviously keep getting the wrong answer. I know how to calculate a geometric sum from an equation but it is difficult for me to calculate it from a set of numbers   ([image: math]

Comment: What are the $a$ and $r$ for the series that *isn't* there?  I.e., can you write the sum that is given as a first sum minus a second sum, where the first sum contains the given numbers and the second sum contains all the numbers after the given numbers?

Comment: this picture is all the information the homework contains, everything else is  just points and question #

Comment: I'm not asking if there is more on the paper, I am asking what you can figure out.

Comment: i figured out that a= 1/5 because it is the first number in the series and r= (1/20)/(1/5) which is 1/4  from there i plug into the numbers in the equation which is : .2(1-.25^n)/(1-.25) resulting in .2((1-.25^n)/.75)

Comment: Now what do you have to subtract from that to get the (much shorter) sum in the problem?

Comment: honestly, I have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each term is $1/4$ the previous term, so $r=1/4$. Your first term, corresponding to the zero power of $1/4$ is $1/5$, so this is your a. Then, to figure out where the series terminates, you must find out what power of $1/4$ yields the equality
$$
\frac{1}{5*4^n}=\frac{1}{20,480}\Rightarrow 4^n=\frac{20,480}{5}=2*2^{11}=2^{12}=4^6\Rightarrow n=6
$$ 
Then use the familiar formula for a finite geometric sum with n terms, 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}ar^k=a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}
$$ 
with $r=1/4$ and $a=1/5$ as we found.

Comment: Solving for $n$ is a distraction.  You can just start the subtracted series with the next term, $\dfrac{1}{4 \times 20\,480}$.

Comment: @EricTowers a distraction or just a different way to solve the problem?